# How to render other component from children on onClick event react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I render another component from one component's HTML element on onClick event?

```
//ChildComp.jsx

import NextElement from "./NextElement";

const AuxMenu = () => {
  
  const [element, setElement] = useContext(ElementContext);
  
  function changeState(e){
    setElement(e.target.innerText)
  } 
  
  return (
    <div onClick={(e)=>{changeState(e) && <NextElement />}}>Click me</div>
  );
};

export default AuxMenu;


//NextElement.jsx

imr
function NextElement(){
  return <button>Next Button</button>
}
```

This is indeed a wrong code, I just wanted to show the reference.

Query: When a `div` is clicked, the `changeState()` should update the element name in *state* and then it should render to the `NextElement` component and replace/remove the previous component. (Something like what React router does, but my app is single page application so I don't have paths or links to define)

**Edited:**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kinda what you're looking for.

Let me know if you have any questions.

```js
//ChildComp.jsx
import NextElement from "./NextElement";

const AuxMenu = () => {
  
  const [showElement, setShowElement] = useState(false);
  
  function changeState(){
    setShowElement(!showElement)
  } 
  
  return (
    <>
      {!showElement && <div onClick={changeState}>
        Click me
      </div>}
      {showElement && <NextElement />}
    </>
  );
};

export default AuxMenu;


//NextElement.jsx
function NextElement(){
  return <button>Next Button</button>
}
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, I appreciate. I read about that method too. Well, it is actually rendering the `NextElement` within the same component so my UI is abnormally showing me things. I want the old component to be replaced.

Comment: your answer is very close @fortunee . can you please help me in replacing the old component?

Answer (score 1):

Like with React Router, you'll need to define your routes, or in this case, **steps**. The easiest way to do it is to create a component for each step, like `FirstStep`, `SecondStep`, etc.

Then create an array. This array will contain functions that return the step components. The order in the array determines the order of the steps.

```
// You'll have to create the components yourself.
import { FirstStep, SecondStep } from './components'; 

// Put them in an array.
const steps = [
  (props) => <FirstStep {...props} />,
  (props) => <SecondStep {...props />,
];
```

Now in your main component (`AuxMenu`), keep an index that tracks the current position in the steps, starting at `0`.

Use this index to select the component from the `steps` array and render it.

Now when you want to go to the next step, all you'll have to do is increase the current position in the array. So `currentStep + 1` will give you your next step.

```
// The steps array.
import { steps } from './steps';

const AuxMenu = () => {
  const [currentStep, setCurrentStep] = useState(0);

  const hasNextStep = currentStep + 1 < steps.length;
  
  const nextStep = () => {
    if (hasNextStep) {
      setCurrentStep(currentStep => currentStep += 1);
    }
  };

  const StepComponent = steps[currentStep];
  
  return (
    <div>
      <StepComponent someprop={'hello'} />
      {hasNextStep && <button onClick={nextStep}>Next step</button>}
    <div/>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you @Emiel. I am not doing conditional rendering actually. Its like you had an input box on your screen for First name and when you entered then the Last name input box appears, the first one disappears (replaced to be precise)

Comment: Well, that's actually exactly what *conditional rendering* is; `if (first name is filled) show last name`. Your question remains unclear. Do you just want to hide / show an element with CSS? Or navigate through steps or something?

Comment: Yeah navigate is the correct thing (navigate from previous child component to next child component but when a button is clicked in previous comp), like I said in question somewhat like Router but I don't have paths and links to offer

Comment: Okay, we're getting closer. But do you have steps then? Like page 1, 2, 3, etc. where you want to cycle through? That part is missing from your question. We don't know what the steps look like and how many there are. Is it just 2? Or will there be more? When will you go to the next step? Do the steps have names?

Comment: Just 2 for now, if the steps is the only method then yeah I hv done that already by setting up the steps in state

Comment: Wow that was cool! I can run my app in frames with that. Will surely try this. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

It’s hard to say without seeing what’s inside of ElementContext, but it looks like you’re setting text to be stored in element.

Say you have 2 components A & B as such:

```
const A = () => {
  const [element, setElement] = useContext(ElementContext);
  return (
    <p onClick={() => setElement(“B”)}>Hello</p>
  )
}

const B = () => {
  return (
    <p>Goodby</p>
  )
}
```

And some parent component P as such:

```
const P = () => {
  const [element, setElement] = useContext(ElementContext);
  return (
    <>
      {element === ‘A’ ? <A /> : <B />}
    </>
  )
}
```

The parent will render the A component initially (assuming “A” is the default value of ElementContext) and B if the paragraph tag in A is clicked.

Comment: Nah not conditional rendering @Leshawn. I want as the Fortunee answered but that lacks too